# remove lines with duplicate words

Tags: linux, bash, uniq

I have a sorted file with lines like this

```
word1  abca
word1  abcb
word1  abcc
word2  abca
word2  abcb
word3  abbb
...........
```

and i want to have something like this

```
word1  abca
word2  abca
word3  abbb
...........
```

Comment: You need to provide more details. Do you only need the first entry for each word1, word2...?

Comment: it doesn't matter if it's the first entry or the second or the next one and so one, it has to be only one line with word1 or word2 etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This magic incantation is a famous awk idiom:

```
awk '!seen[$1]++' file
```

The first time a line with that $1 is seen, the line is printed.

Answer (score 1):

An awk solution - using a variable to detect a new word. If a new word is found, print the line and assign the variable to the current word.

As the data file is sorted, only the 1st occurence of each word will print the record.

```
   awk 'BEGIN{w=""} w!=$1 {print;w=$1}' your-file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `-w` flag of `uniq` which tells it to only compare the first N characters. The details of whether this will work for you depend on your actual data but if the word lengths are set or limited, it should work:

```
$ sort file.txt | uniq -w 5
word1  abca
word2  abca
word3  abbb
```

Alternatively, reverse the order of the fields and use `uniq -f 1` to skip comparing the 1st field:

```
$ awk '{print $2,$1}' file.txt | uniq -f 1 | awk '{print $2,$1}'
word1 abca
word2 abca
word3 abbb
```

Or get the 1st fields and then `grep` for them, limiting the search to the first match:

```
$ for i in $(awk '{print $1}' file.txt | sort -u); do grep -m 1 $i file.txt; done
word1  abca
word2  abca
word3  abbb
```

And, for completion's sake, a Perl one:

```
$ perl -ane 'print if $k{$F[0]}++<1' file.txt 
word1  abca
word2  abca
word3  abbb
```